# How to implement properties of C# in PHP?

Tags: c#, php

[This is the way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx) properties are defined in C# language.

In C# unlike in PHP, class properties are not simple variables and when you set or get their values, accessor functions are called. So you can lock a property from being changed after initialization. In php it seems without function name followed by parentheses you can't call such value. Is there any similar concept in PHP for that?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to have get and set methods in PHP using the [__get and __set magic methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) (though the implementation is different from C#)

```
class A {
    protected $test_int;

    function __construct() {
        $this->test_int = 2;
    }

    function __get($prop) {
        if ($prop == 'test_int') {
            echo 'test_int get method<br>';
            return $this->test_int;
        }
    }

    function __set($prop, $val) {
        if ($prop == 'test_int') {
            echo 'test_int set method<br>';
            //$this->test_int = $val;
        }
    }
}

$obj = new A();
$obj->test_int = 3; //Will echo 'test_int set method'
echo $obj->test_int; //Will echo 'test_int get method' and then the value of test_int.
```

If you want to "lock" a property's value, simply do:

```
function __set($prop, $val) {
    if ($prop == 'test_int') {
        //Do nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, but "maybe" in future versions of PHP.
RFC: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/propertygetsetsyntax
Magic _*get/*_set and "overloading", are various cases of code smell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are meaning.

But if you'r talking about getters and setters, you can simply declare your var as private and make a public method to get the value.

```
private $lol;
public getlol(){
   return $this->lol;
}
```

But if you'r talking about contants you need try it:

```
define("MAXSIZE", 100);
```